# How to display blob URL in react native (expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, blob, imagepicker

I'm trying to get an image to show up using a blob url instead of a local file.

This is an example blob url: `blob:602342de-a839-442f-9c91-877301955502?offset=0&size=35`

This is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
  var byteString;
  if (dataURI.split(",")[0].indexOf("base64") >= 0)
    byteString = atob(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
  else byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(",")[1]);

  // separate out the mime component
  var mimeString = dataURI.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];

  // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
  var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString });
}

export default function App() {
  const [blobUrl, setBlobUrl] = useState(null);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      base64: true,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      let imgBlob = dataURItoBlob(result.assets[0].uri);
      let blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imgBlob);
      setBlobUrl(blobUrl);
      //  setBlobUrl(result.assets[0].uri);
      console.log(blobUrl);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImage}>
        <Text>Pick Image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {blobUrl && (
        <Image
          source={{ uri: blobUrl }}
          style={{ width: 300, height: 200, marginBottom: 5 }}
        />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

If I use the local file uri `result.assets[0].uri` the image shows up. But using the blob uri, the image doesn't. What do I have wrong here?

Please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the conversion from a data URI to a Blob object using the dataURItoBlob function. The function you provided seems to be designed for handling data URIs that contain base64-encoded data or URL-encoded data. However, the blob URL you have provided (e.g., blob:602342de-a839-442f-9c91-877301955502?offset=0&size=35) is not a data URI but rather a URL generated by the browser. you can directly use the blob URL as the image source.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

export default function App() {
  const [blobUrl, setBlobUrl] = useState(null);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      base64: false, // Don't request base64 data
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setBlobUrl(result.uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImage}>
        <Text>Pick Image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {blobUrl && (
        <Image
          source={{ uri: blobUrl }}
          style={{ width: 300, height: 200, marginBottom: 5 }}
        />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

With these changes, when you select an image using the image picker, the blob URL will be set as the image source, and it should be displayed correctly in the  component.

Comment: Isn't `result.uri` a path to a local file? I thought if I convert it to a blob, I will be able to save the data apart from the local file path and then send it to my server and database. What should I do?

Comment: To upload the image data to your server, you can convert the local file to a blob using the fetch API and response.blob(), then send the blob data using an HTTP request library like Axios.

Comment: Ok, and then if I retrieve a blob from the backend, how would I display it as an `Image`? It sounds like I can't leave it in a blob format right? Would I save the local uri along with the blob? Where I'm confused, is that a local file from my phone, won't show up correctly on someone else's phone, or am I wrong about that?